# linking css and javascript files when using dynamically created subdomains and mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need some help figuring out how to link css and javascript files when using subdomains for my site.

We have a CMS that allows users to have their own subdomain (eg.  user1.mydomain.com).  We want the user to be directed to a "site_index.php" page and pass the subdomain as a querystring parameter when they type in their subdomain, which is why we have the following mod_rewrite rule in our apache config.

Heres the mod_rewrite inside the apache httpd.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   ####RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).mydomain.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /administrator/sites_index.php?subdomain=%2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Inside the "sites_index.php" page we then take the subdomain and validate it and present the html for that specific subdomain.  Each user can have their own css template.  The problem I'm having comes from using a relative path for the .css files and the .js files.
Here's how I want to link to them:

```
<link href="public_site_templates/css_templates/common.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="public_site_templates/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What happens with the above link, is the HTML loads, but the css and javascript never links up.

If I hardcode the path like so:

```
<link href="http://www.mydomain.com/administrator/public_site_templates/css_templates/common.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://www.mydomain.com/administrator/public_site_templates/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then everything links up properly.  I checked the "relative path" and everything should link up, but it doesn't.

Is there something I can do to fix this?  Is there a better way I should be doing this? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore js and css files.

I've added: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !((.*).(js|css))$ [NC]`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !((.*).(js|css))$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).mydomain.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /administrator/sites_index.php?subdomain=%2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm not sure the regexp `!((.*).(js|css))$` is ok... try it!

Please could you tell me if it works?

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

May I ask you to add the rewritelog in your question?

Comment: tried this, but got the same result.  Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: the basic principle is to apply those rules only if is doesn't match the regexp which is "end by css or js" => **`!(\.(css|js))$`** mayb my regexp is not good but I'm pretty sure if you find the right one that follows the principle everything will work.

Answer (score -1):

The html `<base>` tag might be what you're looking for.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4

(assuming you tried something like this and it didn't work)

```
<link href="/administrator/public_site_templates/css_templates/common.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/administrator/public_site_templates/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: this works, but is not much different than hardcoding the url like I did before.  Thanks anyway for the response.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'm not sure what you're looking for. How do you want the URLs to look?